# PHP - can't delete mysqli values in the way I want

Tags: php, mysqli

Sorry for the ambiguous title, I don't know how else to name this.
I need to delete specific values in specific quantities from my database. I have a table with some numbers. It looks something like this

1,2(1),3,4,5(6),6(3),7(2),8,9(4),10

The numbers in brackets represent how many times a base number is found in the mysqli database. My form lets me select multiple duplicate numbers and how many duplicates of a number I want to delete. So for example I have selected:

2(1),5(4),9(2)

This is the code that gives me those values but it is imperfect because I receive all the numbers that have at least one duplicate in the database and empty values where there is no number selected and normal numbers when it's selected.

`<input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" min="0" max='<?php echo "$count[$item]"?>' />
input type="hidden" name="hidden[]" id="hidden" value='<?php echo "$item" ?>' />`

My thought process is that I needed to build the code so that I knew exactly the number that was selected for the amount of times it is selected. So I wanted to make an associative array from the 2 values that I am supposed to receive. It works, it gives me that information, but I just can't make it delete selected items the number of times that I want, it deletes all the existing duplicates of the selected items.

```
 $arr1 = array();

 $arr2 = array();

 $newAssoc = array();

 if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
   $hidden = $_POST['hidden'];

   foreach( $hidden as $var1 ) {
     $arr1[] = $var1;
   }

   foreach( $quantity as $var2 ) {
     $arr2[] = $var2;
   }

   $newAssoc = array_combine( $arr1, $arr2 );

   foreach( $newAssoc as $key => $val ) {
     if( !empty($val)) {
       $i = 1;

       while( $i <= $val ) {
         $delete = mysqli_query( $db, "DELETE FROM duplicates
                                        WHERE numbers=$key" );
          ++$i;

       }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried quite a few things and I'm in a bit of a pickle because nothing worked and I'm out of ideas.

EXPECTED RESULT: I will repeat myself, I need to delete specific values in specific quantities from my database.

Sorry for the wall of text and horrendous code/coding practice/coding logic, still a bit new to both coding and stackoverflow.

Thank you for your help RiggsFolly, your answer has fixed all my problems. If anyone has anything interesting to add I don't mind. Thank you !

***This is the portion of the code that was changed in order for my expected result to be fullfiled, if anyone needs it:***

```
  foreach( $newAssoc as $key => $val ) {
     if( !empty($val)) {

         $delete = mysqli_query( $db, "DELETE FROM duplicates
                                       WHERE numbers=$key
                                       LIMIT $val" );

  }
```

Comment: Too lazy to search for a duplicate, but use `limit`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html

Comment: Can you add your answer in an answer rather than comment ? So I can select it as the right answer ? It fixed all my problems, thank you so much ! I did not expect it to be so easy... Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

On single tables, you can limit the number of rows deleted by using `limit`.

Your query would look something like `DELETE FROM table WHERE key=value LIMIT 10`. See [the official documentation of mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html).